# Want to change month name to number in ionic date picker

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using this code for getting dates but I want to show month number instead of month name how can I do that
`<ion-datetime presentation="date" prefer-wheel="true" color="#ee67ab" (ionChange)="onDatetimeChange()"></ion-datetime>`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with ion-datetime, but you can use ion-picker to have the result you want

the HTML will be something like this (showDateTime is a boolean that you will use to show and hide the ion-picker):

```
<ion-picker [isOpen]="showDateTime" [columns]="monthYearPickerColumns" [buttons]="monthYearPickerButtons"></ion-picker>
```

For the months, the years and the buttons, you can use the following configuration :

```
monthOptions = Array.from(new Array(12), (x, i) => i + 1).map(val => ({
  text: (val+'').padStart(2, '0'),
  value: val,
}));

yearOptions = Array.from(new Array(176), (x, i) => i + 1924).map(val => ({
  text: `${val}`,
  value: val,
}));

public monthYearPickerColumns: PickerColumn[] = [
  {
    name: 'month',
    options: this.monthOptions,
    selectedIndex: this.monthOptions.findIndex(option => option.value === ((new Date).getMonth()+1))
  },
  {
    name: 'year',
    options: this.yearOptions,
    selectedIndex: this.yearOptions.findIndex(option => option.value === ((new Date).getFullYear()))
  },
];

public monthYearPickerButtons: PickerButton[] = [
  {
    text: 'Cancel',
    role: 'cancel',
  },
  {
    text: 'Ok',
    handler: (data) => {
      console.log(data.month.value);
      console.log(data.year.value);
    },
  },
];
```